# [WebLogic][ClassNotFoundException] Deployment on cluster

Tags: java, oracle, exception, weblogic, classnotfoundexception

I'm facing a problem I try to solve for two days. I try to deploy a project on a cluster weblogic from JDeveloper 11g. My cluster consists of three weblogic servers running on my local machine

JDev messages

```
[04:34:19 PM] [Deployer:149034]An exception occurred for task [Deployer:149026]deploy application /ServerV3.1 on cluster1.: oracle/security/idm/IMException.
[04:34:19 PM] Weblogic Server Exception: weblogic.application.ModuleException: oracle/security/idm/IMException
[04:34:19 PM] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.security.idm.IMException
[04:34:19 PM]   See server logs or server console for more details.
[04:34:19 PM] weblogic.application.ModuleException: oracle/security/idm/IMException
[04:34:19 PM] ####  Deployment incomplete.  ####
[04:34:19 PM] Remote deployment failed
```

Weblogic error log

```
####<15 mai 2013 16 h 34 CEST> <Error> <Deployer> <tolsa_c-PC> <node1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <7e8cd60e5001b48f:-32d63ec8:13ea82d211a:-7ff4-000000000000002c> <1368628459177> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1368628457259' for task '17'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: oracle/security/idm/IMException'
weblogic.application.ModuleException: oracle/security/idm/IMException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1512)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.security.idm.IMException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.<clinit>(JpsFilter.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.getNewInstance(WebComponentContributor.java:225)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.createFilterInstance(WebComponentContributor.java:257)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.loadFilter(FilterManager.java:94)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.preloadFilters(FilterManager.java:59)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1876)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
> 
####<15 mai 2013 16 h 34 CEST> <Error> <Deployer> <tolsa_c-PC> <node1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <7e8cd60e5001b48f:-32d63ec8:13ea82d211a:-7ff4-000000000000002c> <1368628459180> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 1 task for the application '/ServerV3.1'.>
```

I've tried to add "BC4J Runtime" which CONTAINS "oracle.security.idm.IMException" to my classpath and to the deployment libs but it doesn't solve my error.

Comment: Where exactly have you added it (and how)? You need to put it in the `EXT_PRE_CLASSPATH` environment variable I think, since WLS ignores your session class path, and you'd need to bounce the server(s) to pick that up. I haven't done this in Windows (?); in Linux I'd have a start-up script to set things like this so I guess you can do that in .bat file, which is maybe preferable to changing the supplied start/env scripts manually.

Comment: I've add it from JDevelopper -> Project Properties -> Library and Classpath -> Add Library .And secondly Deployment -> Edit -> Contributors lib -> add

Comment: I don't use JDeveloper, but won't that only make it visible to the JDeveloper IDE so you can code and build against it? I don't think it automagically makes WebLogic aware of it for runtime.

Comment: In fact, when I specify that my projet is using those libraries in JDev, it will automatically add the libs to weblogic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in my nodemanager.properties file the value "StartScriptEnable" was set to false. I set it to true and then, my admin server and my manager server were able to share libraries